# Match POSIXct in one dataset to a range of POSIXct in another dataset

Tags: r

I'm trying to match the time (in POSIXct) found in one dataset (Detection), to within a range of times (in POSIXct) data in another dataset (GPS); then copy the GPS coordinates found in the second dataset to their relevant positions in the first dataset.

I have two datasets: one with detection data, and one with GPS coordinates and arrival/departure times).

Example of the detection data:

```
Time                   Receiver    Transmitter    Latitude    Longitude
2015-10-29 14:17:31    Boat        A69-25863      NA          NA
2015-10-29 14:23:49    Boat        A69-25863      NA          NA
2015-10-29 14:25:49    Boat        A69-25863      NA          NA
2015-11-22 14:38:57    Boat        A69-25864      NA          NA
2015-11-22 14:40:06    Boat        A69-25864      NA          NA
(5429 entries)
```

Time is in POSIXct format, the transmitters are factors.

Example of the GPS data:

```
ArrivalLocation  ArrivalTime           ArrivalLon   ArrivalLat  DepartureTime   
Saint Blaize     2015-10-29 12:19:08   22.14484     -34.17841   2015-10-29 14:38:29
Pansy Beach      2015-10-29 15:04:17   22.12347     -34.16677   2015-10-29 15:27:45
Santosstrand     2015-10-29 15:44:23   22.13361     -34.16975   2015-10-29 16:14:40
Santosstrand     2015-10-29 16:29:32   22.13642     -34.17137   2015-10-29 16:58:39
Seal Island      2015-11-22 13:49:30   22.12081     -34.14991   2015-11-22 18:25:05
Saint Blaize     2015-11-22 18:40:19   22.14519     -34.17847   2015-11-25 09:07:18
(669 entries)
```

Both ArrivalTime and DepartureTime are in POSIXct format.

Now I want to copy the GPS coordinates from the second dataset to their relevant positions in the first dataset.

Example: 
The first detection at `2015-10-29 14:17:31` falls within range of the first GPS coordinates: `Saint Blaize` at `2015-10-29 12:19:08` and `2015-10-29 14:38:29`. Then the coordinates `-34.17841` and `22.14484` should be copied to their relevant cells in the detection dataset:

```
Time                   Receiver    Transmitter    Latitude    Longitude
2015-10-29 14:17:31    Boat        A69-25863      -34.17841   22.14484
```

Considering I have over 5400 entries (and growing), this would be a chore if done manually.

I've tried working with `ifelse()`, `match()` and `if(){}` functions, to no avail.

```
Detection$Latitude <- ifelse(Detection$Time >= GPS$ArrivalTime & Detection$Time <= GPS$DepartureTime, GPS$ArrivalLat, Detection$Latitude) 
Detection$Latitude <- GPS[match(Detection$Time >= GPS$ArrivalTime & Detection$Time <= GPS$DepartureTime), "ArrivalLat"]
```

I suspect there is an issue with the way I specify the range, but this might not be the biggest error.

(This is my first post/question on stack overflow, so my apologies if things are not clear enough.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working solution.  Because you are comparing one vector to all the values in another vector, I when with a simple loop.  Since your gps data frame is less than 1000 entries performance shouldn't be to awful.  I believe there should be a more efficient method.

I used the `between` function from the `dplyr` package.
Assuming your dataframes are named "detection" and "gps" and the time columns are in POSIXct format:

```
library(dplyr)
for (i in 1:length(gps$ArrivalTime)){
  isbewteen<-between(detection$Time, gps$ArrivalTime[i], gps$DepartureTime[i])
  detection$Latitude[isbewteen ]<-gps$ArrivalLat[i]
  detection$Longitude[isbewteen ]<-gps$ArrivalLon[i]
}
```